# matrix for this system of non-linear equation?

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, nonlinear-system

Let's consider the product of a square matrix and a vector: $
M{\times}v =
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3\\ 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 7 & 8 & 9 \end{bmatrix}
{\times}
\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} 1 {\times} a + 2 {\times} b + 3 {\times} c \\
                4 {\times} a + 5 {\times} b + 6 {\times} c \\
                7 {\times} a + 8 {\times} b + 9 {\times} c \end{bmatrix}$

How can I write $M$ such that $M{\times}v=
\begin{bmatrix} 1 {\times} a + 2 {\times} b + a {\times} b \\
                4 {\times} a + 5 {\times} b + a {\times} c \\
                7 {\times} a + 8 {\times} b + b {\times} c \end{bmatrix}$

The difference is in the third column where it's not just some constant times $c$ but the product of two other inputs.

**Update**

Ben suggested using the input variables $a$ and $b$ directly in the matrix $M$, but then $M$ wouldn't be made of constants only (like in the first example)

Comment: Thanks in advance to whomever will take the time to respond.

Comment: Are we allowed to take
$$
M = \pmatrix{1&2&a\\4&5&a\\7&8&b}
$$
in this context?

Comment: That's a valid answer, but unfortunately, no. The question is about how to model non-linear systems using a matrix. I've seen some examples but couldn't figure how to do it in this case. I'll add this precision to the question. Thanks.

Comment: @BenGrossmann : third entry, first row has to be $ab/c$.

Comment: @Eric Could you add a link to or summarize an example of what you mean by "modeling a non-linear system using a matrix"? By definition, any equation of the form $Mv = y$ where the entries of $v$ are all unknown and all other entries are known will be a *linear* system.

Comment: Your very, very specific question "How can I write $M$ such that ..." has no answer, because there is no such way.  Can you relax any part of the requirements?  Can we expand to [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates)?  Can we use more interesting products, like $v^T \cdot M \cdot v$ or perhaps more terms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Define $$v_1 = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array} \right]$$
and $$v_2 = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right]$$
By your definition: $$M v_1 = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 4 \\ 7 \end{array} \right]$$
and $$M v_2 = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 2 \\ 5 \\ 8 \end{array} \right]$$
However, $$M (v_1 + v_2) = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 4 \\ 9 \\ 15 \end{array} \right] \neq M v_1 + M v_2$$
Remember that matrix multiplication by a vector is a linear operator.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}$Let
$$\eqalign{
P &= \m{1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&8&9}\qquad a = \m{a\\b\\c} \\
}$$
Then what you have is a linear equation $(Mv = Pa)$ which you wish to solve for $M$. This can be accomplished using an *arbitrary* matrix $A,\,$ and $v^+$ the [Moore-Penrose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) inverse of $v$.
$$\eqalign{
M &= (Pa)v^+ + A(I-vv^+) \\
  &= Pa\left(\frac{v^T}{v^Tv}\right) + A\left(I-\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}\right) \\
  &= \left(\frac{Pav^T+(v^Tv)A-Avv^T}{v^Tv}\right) \\
}$$
Note that this isn't a unique solution, it's a whole family of solutions; one for each $A$ matrix.